# Android Studio - Program type already present : com.google.android.gms.actions.SearchIntents

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

This error pops up when i tried to build or run my project.

```
Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.actions.SearchIntents
```

Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.actions.SearchIntents, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

Things that i've tried according to a thread that i found related to this:

- Invalidate Cache & restart
- Clean Project

Changing firebase version like so

- 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2' > 16.0.0
- 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.1' > 16.0.1
- 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0' > 16.0.1

Changing google-services version 3.2.1 > 3.3.0

Here's my build.gradle app

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
      //  classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.3'
        classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.8.2'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.arc.Dobyt"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 4
        versionName "3.0.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    annotationProcessor 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
  //  implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2'
   // implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1'
    implementation  'com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1'
    implementation  'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:4.3.1"
    implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:4.3.1"
   // implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
  //  implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
   // implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'

    implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'actions'
    }
    implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'actions'
    }
    implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'actions'
    }
    implementation  'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'//materialEditText
    implementation 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.2'
   // implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
    // Facebook SDK
  //  implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.33.0'
   // implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.33.0'
    //implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:4.33.0'
    //implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-places:4.33.0'
   // implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-messenger:4.33.0'
  //  implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:4.33.0'
    implementation ('com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.33.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'cardview-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'customtabs'
    }
    implementation ('com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.33.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'cardview-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'customtabs'
    }
    implementation ('com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:4.33.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'cardview-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'customtabs'
    }

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'//Glide
    implementation 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.3.1'
    //firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'

    implementation 'com.androidadvance:topsnackbar:1.1.1'//Top Snack
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'//cardview
    //location update
   // implementation 'com.akhgupta:android-easylocation:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.0.5'
    implementation ('com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.0.5') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'gms'
    }
    // GeoFire
    implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.polok.routedrawer:library:1.0.0'//Route drawer
    //crashlytic
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'
```

My build.gradle project

```js
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and my AndroidManifest.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.arc.Dobyt">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.rider.aracanemap.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Google Plus permission -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".adapter.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"
        >
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".LocationService" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SignUp_Activity_"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SigninActivity_"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ForgotPasswordActivity_"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LaunchActivity_">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider637950799925113"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity android:name=".DocUpload_Activity_" />
        <activity android:name=".ImageUpload_" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Map_Activity_"
            android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">

        </activity>


        <activity android:name=".IntentActivity" />

        <activity android:name=".TabActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingActivity_"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".EditProfileActivity_"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".RatingActivity_">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".EarningActivity_">
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="58ed39c94fbcd33ec9afa9b3b5b81a533b1c320a" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I would really appreciate it if anyone can show or guide me the way because i have spent 2 days trying to find the source of the problem and sometimes even with the same code it either spit out error

```
Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.actions.SearchIntents

OR



Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.actions.ReserveIntents
```

Comment: try changing  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0' to classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'

Comment: Changing firebase dependency from 3.2.0 to 3.3.0 sometimes work

Comment: @AkshayNandwana tried that, still the same error, 3.3.0, 3.2.1 or 3.2.0

Answer (score 0):

The Error `Program type already present` usually comes from *mixing dependency versions* which can lead to runtime crash. So **try to use compatible versions**.

In your case, I think excluding *actions* module can make debugging more harder. Then try to match used versions inside `dependencies>implementation` and `buildscript>dependencies>classpath` after executing the commands `gradlew app:dependencies` and `gradlew dependencies`.